# Largest number of perfect matchings in bounded genus graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, perfect-matchings

What is the largest number of perfect matchings a genus $g$ bipartite graph on $n+m$ vertices have?

Comment: Have you tried working out the values for some small values of n or m?

Comment: $g$ scales with $n$ it is unlikely you get a nice formula so easily